# Speech to Text Noise Issues

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text

I have an issue that I am trying to resolve. I am trying to capture meeting minutes from a recorder. When one person is presenting, the speech to text works great. The issue is when there are side conversations, paper ruffling or just general noise, the recorder picks up all these noises. The speech to text does not make sense. At times, I can have 25 people in a meeting room. Any suggestions on a solution?